# Shorten title on each beamer slide

Tags: beamer, titles

In a beamer presentation the title is long but ok for the first slide. The problem is that when the title appears below on each slide it is very long and I would like to use here some sort of running or shorter title, how can this be done?

Comment: IIRC: `\title[short]{long}`  as with sectioning commands.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Beamer supports the usual syntax of sectioning commands where you can provide an alternative short version of the title as optional argument, which is then used for the footer (or header, depending on style):

```
\title[<short version for footer>]{<long version for titlepage>}
```

Comment: In my beamer template the short title does not show up? Do you have any Idea how I can add this later on?