# presentation title out of range using Boadilla theme

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to prepare a presentation in LaTeX using Beamer. I'm using the Boadilla theme. unfortunately I have troubles in the title of the presentation because it is too small. 
I tried to enlarge it using "bold" but unfortunately the title in  the lower bar of the font goes out of range.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you check if [Shorten title on each beamer slide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22402/13304) solves your problem?