# How do I cover the title in the footline of my beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

So the title of the presentation is too long and it doesn't fit in the footline of each frame, so it looks cut off. I'm using the Copenhagen theme.

I need to cover it, or at least put a `[...]` at the end of the title in the footline.

Comment: You can use a short title as an option and I believe that is the one that will show up in the footline. \title[short]{Long}

Comment: Your question might be already asked and answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22405/71924).